# Weird Behaviour when nesting 2D arrays in a 3D array

Tags: javascript, debugging, multidimensional-array

Currently I'm working on a Minimax algorithm for four-in-a-row in javascript. I have decided to store possible moves in a array, continuing to nest arrays within arrays for every branch.

However, when I attempt to edit a certain value in an array, it edits all other values within the same column.

Code:

```
var BOARD = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
    ];

// Put 3 x 2D Arrays into one 3D Array
var NODE_TREE = [BOARD, BOARD, BOARD];
NODE_TREE[1][2][0] = 2;
console.log(NODE_TREE);
```

Chrome V8 interpreter output:

```
[ [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 2, 0, 0 ] ],
  [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 2, 0, 0 ] ],
  [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 2, 0, 0 ] ] ]
```

What should happen but dosen't:

```
[ [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ],
  [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 2, 0, 0 ] ],
  [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ] ]
```

Javascript seems to ignore the First dimension index number. This issue only happens when I use an existing array nested within an array. If I were to make a 3D array from scratch, this bug does not happen.

Comment: you add a reference to the array, wihout making a deep copy of the values.

Comment: @NinaScholz Could you please make an example, I have looked up what referencing is, however, I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lazy initalization, you could use a parsed [JSON](http://json.org/) string.

This generates an independent object without references to the original object.

```js
var BOARD = [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]
    ],
    JSON_BOARD = JSON.stringify(BOARD),
    NODE_TREE = [JSON.parse(JSON_BOARD), JSON.parse(JSON_BOARD), JSON.parse(JSON_BOARD)];

NODE_TREE[1][2][0] = 2;
console.log(NODE_TREE);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put `BOARD` 3 times in to the array, you are not "copying" the items in to the new array, you are actually just creating 3 references to the original `BOARD` array.

Therefore any change made to any one of those references will be reflected in all instances of `BOARD`.

If you want to create 3 distinct arrays in your 3d array you will need to clone or copy the arrays. You can do this by mapping on the outer array and copy the contents with Array.prototype.slice();

```js
var BOARD = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
    ];
    
// function to map and copy arrays with .slice()
function sliceArrays (outerArray){
  return outerArray.map((arr)=>{
    return arr.slice()
  });
}

var NODE_TREE = [sliceArrays(BOARD), sliceArrays(BOARD), sliceArrays(BOARD)];
NODE_TREE[1][2][0] = 2;
console.log(NODE_TREE);

//[ [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ],
//  [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 2, 0, 0 ] ],
//  [ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ] ]
```

Comment: The same problem is still present.

Comment: I am using primitive values, yet I still get the problem.

Comment: Sorry you're totally right, I've updated the answer to map over and slice the arrays inside